# How to find the network router's model programmatically

Tags: c#, router

I have a router in my local network (Model: D-Link Micro Httd), and I know its IP address. I want to find the model of router programattically using C#. Also on the router the SNMP service is disabled and I forgot the admin password.
I used the [LanSweeper](http://www.lansweeper.com) NMS, and it finds the model, and also I used the [nMap](http://nmap.org/) and it finds the model too. 
Also I used the UPnP APIs, but even it can't find the router.

How do this Apps find the router's model, whereas the SNMP service is disabled and I forgot the admin password?

Comment: Do they display the full model number, or only the manufacturer? They could get that from the MAC address.

Comment: They get the manufacture from the MAC address, but they get the model name, for example they give me the "Micro_Httpd" for the model. And I don't know that they how do this?

Comment: Maybe they use UPnp correctly and you do not?

Comment: I find some projects that use the UPnP (In GitHub and CodePlex), But they can't find the router.

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700179/how-to-get-device-type-from-mac-or-ip-address, said that the port scanning can give more information, How can I do this? The port scanning only says that the special port is opened or closed. Is it right?

Comment: That suggests that maybe you need to _learn_ UPnP instead of just copying code you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the devices MAC address, then you can use an online service like this one here to fetch the associated metadata stored against the MAC address.

http://www.macvendorlookup.com/api

An example would be:

http://www.macvendorlookup.com/api/v2/00-23-AB-7B-58-99

Which returns the following:

```
[
   {
      "startHex":"0023AB000000",
      "endHex":"0023ABFFFFFF",
      "startDec":"153192759296",
      "endDec":"153209536511",
      "company":"CISCO SYSTEMS, INC.",
      "addressL1":"170 W. TASMAN DRIVE",
      "addressL2":"M\/S SJA-2",
      "addressL3":"SAN JOSE CA 95134-1706",
      "country":"UNITED STATES",
      "type":"oui24"
   }
]
```

UPDATE: However you specifically mention the Model Number. Sadly this isn't going to be available on a publicly facing API and UPNP might work for you. But if the router doesn't have UPNP enabled OR it's blocked, then this won't work either. Check out Port Mapper (written in Java) for some inspiration.

https://github.com/kaklakariada/portmapper

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I know and I use this service to find the manufacturer name, But I want to find the device model.

Comment: My apologies. In hindsight, my answer doesn't fully address all aspects of your question. I suggest you try a tool like [Port Mapper](https://github.com/kaklakariada/portmapper). It has a few implementations of UPNP and might help you determine the best library/approach to use. It's open source, but it's in Java, but should get you on the right track.