# Android how get router manufacturer name programmatically

Tags: android, router

Is any way how get router manufacturer name for example "TP-link ...." programmatically ? We can get a lot of information like IP address, mask, speed etc, but I couldn't find the type of router.

Some applications can show this information, so I know that it is possible :-).

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you able to get the MAC address of the router? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747309/how-to-find-the-network-routers-model-programmatically

Comment: Hi Andrew, I can get MAC address of router and from online service get data about router manufacturer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an online service like this one here to fetch the associated metadata stored against the MAC address.

http://www.macvendorlookup.com/api

An example would be:

http://www.macvendorlookup.com/api/v2/00-23-AB-7B-58-99

Which returns the following:

```
[
   {
      "startHex":"0023AB000000",
      "endHex":"0023ABFFFFFF",
      "startDec":"153192759296",
      "endDec":"153209536511",
      "company":"CISCO SYSTEMS, INC.",
      "addressL1":"170 W. TASMAN DRIVE",
      "addressL2":"M\/S SJA-2",
      "addressL3":"SAN JOSE CA 95134-1706",
      "country":"UNITED STATES",
      "type":"oui24"
   }
]
```

Comment: Daniel, thank You for You prompt help. It works perfectly!

Comment: Hi Charles. Great to hear. If you are happy with the answer please accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

For only Manufacturer name, you can also use below service.

http://api.macvendors.com/MAC_Address.

For url would be like this

http://api.macvendors.com/00:23:AB:7B:58:99

You can get response in string format. Example for above service response would be like this

> Cisco Systems, Inc